# use of the pronoun 'it' in extraposition

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I really don't know about this *it* in the sentence:

*[…] I didn't know why I resented **it** so intensely to have them think of me as something newly minted, but **it** was – I am certain – echoes of that idea that had been sounding […]*

1) To me the first and the second *it* refer to: have them think of me as something newly minted

2) However, when I replace *it* with *this* or *that* it doesn't seem to refer to anything.

Kindly, is there another manipulation to make sure of *it*?

Comment: Doesn't the second "it" refer to "echoes"?

Comment: In "it was . . . echoes of that idea", the "it" refers to "echoes", and "that idea" refers to "think of me as something newly minted". But as my deleted comment said, the whole sentence seems to be poorly written.

Comment: For example in this sentence: The constant juxtaposition of (...), made it clear that they thought of both of us as a couple of experimental animals who had no existence outside the laboratory. -  It's clear that IT is the object and we are in presence of a transitive complex sentence, but I can't figure this out in the previous one.

Comment: It would be simpler to analyse this firstly as two sentences. 'I don't know why I resented it so intensely to have them think of me as something newly minted in their private treasury.  But it was – I am certain – echoes of that idea that had been sounding in the chambers of my mind from the time we had arrived in Chicago.' [after Keyes]

Comment: I'd say it _is_ referential ('It's raining' is the example that really leaves you groping for a subject, deferred or notional), but the two-sentence approach brings out the different referents.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, because separated, the first IT seem non-referential, I can't replace the first IT with a nominal.

Comment: Reasonably close is 'To have them think of me as something newly minted –  I resented this [situation / possibility] so intensely, though I didn’t know why I resented it to such a degree.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth or how to kill two birds with one stone... Thank you very much.

Comment: The first sentence is an [Extraposition from NP](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+%22extraposition+from+NP%22) construction, while the second is an [_It_-Cleft](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299+it+cleft). Both use dummy _it_'s, but different ones, in different contexts. The problem is using them both together like this.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is it true: when "It" is related to the extraposed object, we don't talk of "it" as being referential in extraposition constructions? Because in this construction: The constant juxtaposition of “Algernon and Charlie (...) made it clear that they thought of both of us as a couple of experimental animals who had no existence outside the laboratory. It in this sentence seems referential to the construction in that.

Comment: No, we don't talk of them as being referential. They don't have to be, any more than _there_ has to be locative in _There is a man here to see you_. They're features of the construction, nothing more.

Comment: @JohnLawler Understood, thanks. One last question, can you tell that it (the extraposed object) is related to the proposition in that... and anaphoric? (if it is related to the proposition in that for example)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand either question. Both dummy _it_'s are related only to the particular construction they're in.

Answer (score 1):

In both instances, "it" is an expletive pronoun, sometimes referred to as a dummy pronoun.  There is no explicit meaning in either case, no antecedent.  Rather, the word is used to fulfill the syntactical requirements of the sentence.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun

Answer (score 0):

An expletive pronoun would specifically be written, I didn't know why I resented it!  [explanation sentence to ensue].

The dummy pronoun in this instance allows the writer to avoid awkward construction: "I didn't know why I resented having them think of me as something newly minted so intensely, but it was…"

Comment: I don't think you mean "expletive" here?